# C++ calls function of wrong signature

Tags: c++

I've got a header file with this api:

```
class XmlTree {
    public:
    template<typename T> void Set(const std::string& path, const T& val, const std::string& attrib = "") {...}
    template<typename T> void Set(const std::string& path, const T& val, bool encrypt) {...}
}
```

The code is executing this line:

```
static XmlTree get_root_response(const string& api_name, int code = 0) {
    XmlTree output;
    //api_name is a const string&="Wut", code is an int=200
    output.Set<int>("/" + api_name, code, "code"); //on this line
    ...
    return output;
}
```

For some reason this calls the second Set function signature rather than the first. GDB shows this:

```
#1 XmlTree::Set<int> (this=address, path="/Wut", val=@address: 200, encrypt=true)
#2 get_root_response(api_name="Wut", code=200)
```

So clearly the wrong function signature is being called, but I have no idea how on earth it got that bool input to pick the wrong one. Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `"code"` is of type `const char[]` which decays to `const char*`.

A pointer type is implicitly convertible to `bool` (which evaluates to `true` here) while `std::string` requires a constructor call to construct the `std::string` first. So the `bool` overload is favoured and thus picked.

You can fix this by creating a temporary string first:

```
output.Set<int>("/" + api_name, code, std::string("code"));
```

Comment: Oh dangit that looks to be the issue. Wow I'm stupid, thanks.

Comment: Better use the `s` literal suffix from `std::string_literals`

Comment: I think I'm going to change the second function to SetEncrypted instead, and remove the bool input. I'm too used to const char[] converting into std::string automatically.

Answer (score 1):

the pointer evaluating to bool is considered a better match than having to perform a constructor based conversion, if you made the call:

```
output.Set<int>("/" + api_name, code, std::string("code"));
```

you will get the desired overload.